# Examining the Galois group of an quintic irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

Suppose $f$ is a monic irreducible quintic polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$ (necessarily separable), and let $F$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb C$. Let $u_1,\dots,u_5$ denote the distinct roots of $f$ in $F$. Suppose moreover that the following holds:

- (a) $F=\Bbb Q(u_1,u_2)$,
- (b) $u_i\notin \Bbb Q(u_1)$ for $i>1$,
- (c) $u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5$ are conjugates over $\Bbb Q(u_1)$, and
- (d) $u_i-u_j$ are pairwise distinct for all choices of $i,j$.

I want to show that there exists a $\Bbb Q$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $F$ such that $\sigma(u_1)=u_3$ and $\sigma(u_2)=u_5$, and compute the degree of $u_1+u_2$ over $\Bbb Q$.

It is obvious that $[\Bbb Q(u_1):\Bbb Q]=\deg f=5$. (c) implies that the degree of $u_2$ over $\Bbb Q(u_1)$ is $4$, so (b) implies that $[F:\Bbb Q]=20$. I got stuck here. Should I have to examine transitive subgroups of $S_5$ of order $20$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job figuring out that $[F:\Bbb{Q}]=20$. Let's write $G=Gal(F/\Bbb{Q})$ and $K=\Bbb{Q}(u_1)$, $H=Gal(F/K)$.

Roadmap/extended hint:

- How many elements are there in the subgroup $H$?
- For all $\sigma\in G$ why is it that $\sigma(u_1)=u_1$ if and only if $\sigma\in H$?
- As $f$ is irreducible, $G$ acts on the roots transitively, so there exists an automorphism $\alpha\in G$ such that $\alpha(u_1)=u_3$. Let $S$ be the set of such automorphisms $\alpha$. How many elements are there in $S$? Hint: if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in S$ then where will $\alpha_1^{-1}\alpha_2$ map $u_1$?
- If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in S, \alpha_1\neq\alpha_2$, why does it follow that $\alpha_1(u_2)\neq\alpha_2(u_2)$?
- List the possibilities of $\alpha(u_2), \alpha\in S$.
- Is it possible that $u_i+u_j=u_k+u_\ell$ non-trivially?
- How many distinct numbers $u_i+u_j, i\neq j$ are there?
- Why are they all Galois conjugates of each other (= in the same $G$-orbit)?

Comment: It is possible to enumerate transitiv subgroups of order $20$ in $S_5$, they are the normalizers of Sylow $5$-subgroups, but not necessary for the purposes of this exercise.

Comment: 1: $|H|=[F:K]=4$ since $F$ is Galois over $K$, and 2 is obvious since $K=\Bbb Q(u_1)$. For 3, If we fix an element $\alpha \in S$, then $S$ is precisely $\alpha H$, so it has $4$ elements by 1. 4 is obvious since every $\sigma \in G$ is determined by $\sigma(u_1)$ and $\sigma(u_2)$ by (a). Next, 3 and 4 then imply that for each $i=1,2,4,5$, there must exist an $\tau \in S$ such that $\tau(u_2)=u_i$. This finishes the first part.

Comment: For the second part, condition (d) implies that $u_i+u_j$ are pairwise distinct for $1\leq i<j\leq 5$, so there are 10 numbers of them. Each of them is a Galois conjugate of $u_1+u_2$, because the same argument with the first part shows that some $\sigma \in G$ sends $u_1, u_2$ to $u_i, u_j$, respectively, for each pair $(i,j)$. Conversely, any Galois conjugate of $u_1+u_2$ must be of the form $u_i+u_j$. Thus the minimal polynomial of $u_1+u_2$ over $\Bbb Q$, which is necessarily separable, has $10$ distinct roots.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Correct Well done, @probably123